# Can't add Label on Image with using Xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making iOS and Android app with using Xamarin.forms.

Can't I add Label on the Image?

Of course I know using many layout styles. 
But that question is what I want to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't.

Xamarin.Forms [Image](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Image/) don't have `Text` property.

The only option is to use a `Image` and a `Label` or create a `CustomView` for that.

---

[ImageCell](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ImageCell/) is a type of `Cell` to be used in `List`. Using a table with one row could offer you the visual aspect you need but, its not event an good solution.

**Android only Note:** On `Android` a `Label` could have and `Drawable` on left, right, top and bottom. So if you were targeting only `Android` you could have a custom render for the `Label` that adds the image.

Comment: Thanks @jzeferino !